# OS X Leopard (10.5) Server -- Unwanted Emails

Tags: email, mac-osx, email-server, mac-osx-server, osx-leopard

Our OS X Leopard (10.5) server is sending out an email EVERY DAY for a Disk Full Notification on an external HDD we use for Time Machine backups (which manages it's own disk space, so the disk full notifications are useless).

In the Server Admin app, under Settings > Notifications, there's this:[image: Email Notifications]

which is clearly disabled.

The email header and message: http://pastebin.com/V5PZ3Phk

I've been told to **check the mail.log, but it's mostly empty** (except for a few logs in 2011 saying "Postfix mail system is not running".

I've also been told to **check the crontabs, but I'm not sure how to do that** on OS X (or any OS for that matter). Can someone explain how to do this?

Also, if there's any other suggestions on places/things/etc to look at/for, my ears are all open!

Comment: Why so out of date?

Comment: I'm not the money-decision person, so it's pretty much out of my hands.

Comment: 10.5 was replaced over three years ago - and you could upgrade the whole machine for ~$100 - nobody here is likely to respond to this question as it's so out of date and also should've been asked on the apple-specific SE site.

Comment: I tried over there and got no answers/comments at all.

Comment: For the same reason no doubt

Comment: This may sound stupid, but have you tried checking the checkbox, exiting the configuration tool, then going back in and unchecking that checkbox?

Comment: I'll try it, but having added my email to the list of emails and still not receiving any, while the other email that's been there forever gets them every day, makes me think it can't be the same place generating the emails.